# Why does laravel storage get return false when is does not have the right permissions

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I was trying to get a file on the server with

```
Storage::disk('storage')->get($pathDone)
```

but it returned false

```
Storage::disk('storage')->exist($pathDone)
```

returned true

when i tried

```
file_get_contents()
```

it returned

```
Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Is this a design chose of laravel to return false with permission denied and why whould they chose to return false?

Answer (score 0):

On linux env  its probably a permissions problem
try : `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/`

to give permissions to your web directory